# How to check a graph diameter in LOGSPACE?

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

Given a graph G, how can I check that its diameter doesn't exceed log(n) (n is the number of vertices)- by using only O(log(n)) space? (adjacency matrix doesn't seems to help...)